# Slow loading images nativescript

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript

I'm creating a social media application using nativescript + angular. I'm not sure if this is just a nativescript thing but my images are all loading really slow - they are being loaded dynamically through different URLs. In the link below it shows what I mean by 'the images are loading slow'. Is there anything that I can do to make them load faster? I had these ideas but don't know if they're going to work

1. Make them a set height when uploaded to the webserver so they should be faster to load (currently just using mock data so haven't been able to test this)

   - Will probably use cloudinary to store the images (not sure if this is the best or most cost-efficient so if anyone has any input on this please let me know)
2. Make them a set height in the UI (I think this will still load them slowly though)

If anyone has any ideas of what I can do please let me know.

The video to what I'm writing about is called 'Slow-loading-images-android' (I also show some code on the screen so you can sort of see what is there), there is also another one with a problem with images loading weird on iOS but I think if I sort out this problem on android, it might solve the one on iOS as well

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqCHfupkDPkD81s7dtGhImTkbtb-?e=44OyNk

Comment: You may use plugins like [nativescript-image](https://github.com/Akylas/nativescript-image), helps you to cache remote images, show place holder images while downloading the original image etc.,

Comment: Will caching the remote images be helpful if the images are different every time? I don't think it will but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: You are going to have a version key or different url if the image is changed. If you don't I may say it's not best design, you might want to reconsider. Moreover the plugin caches the images, so it can show loading image while downloading.

Comment: I found another solution which isn't really anything like this ^. It is just to use the decodeHeight and decodeWidth properties for the image so it loads alot faster and then when the user taps on an image, it will load the image properly. Thank you for the help though. Also its a social media app so the users will be uploading images so it will save and read the image URLs from a database as when the images are uploaded, they will be stored in a cloud image storage and the url will be saved to the database

Comment: I guess the plugin also has the same option, have to double check. But I'm sure decoded width / height in image module are Android only properties. Generally Android sucks a lot of memory on image processing.

Comment: yeah, after some testing i think it is an android only thing. iOS is coping quite well though even with an older device. I think the best thing to do to is some sort of pagination so it doesn't get any slower even with the ever-growing list of items

Answer (score 0):

One method I found to fix this was to use nativescript-image-cache but this didn't always work very well as the images were still pretty slow to load. The solution I came up with was to add pagination to the API and use an angular *ngFor instead of a ListView. This way they wouldn't disappear due to the ListView and users can load as many images as they want to, when they want them, it won't slow down performance and looks alot better UI wise.

If anyone else comes across a problem like this and doesn't know what to do, here is the code:

Before (With ListView - Bad)

```
    <ListView [items]="feeds" height="100%">
                <ng-template let-item="item" class="feed">

                    <StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <GridLayout class="feed-user" columns="50,20,*" (tap)="getUserById(item.userId)">
                                <Image class="user" [src]="item.mainImage" col="0"></Image>
                                <Label [text]="item.username" class="username" col="2"></Label>
                            </GridLayout>
                            <Image *ngIf="item.isImage" class="feed-image" [src]="item.photoUrl"></Image>
                            <VideoPlayer *ngIf="!item.isImage" [src]="item.photoUrl" autoplay="true" muted="true"
                                height="300">
                            </VideoPlayer>
                            <GridLayout class="like-sect" columns="*,*" (tap)="like(item)">
                                <Image class="like" col="0" src="~/app/_assets/ui-images/like.png"></Image>
                                <Label col="1" class="likes" [text]="item.likes"></Label>
                            </GridLayout>
                            <Label class="caption" [text]="item.description"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                </ng-template>
            </ListView>
```

After (Without ListView - Good)

```
    <ScrollView [height]="height">

        <StackLayout>

            <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of feeds">
                <StackLayout class="feed-body">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image *ngIf="item.isImage" class="feed-image" [src]="item.photoUrl"></Image>
                        <VideoPlayer *ngIf="!item.isImage" [src]="item.photoUrl" autoplay="true" muted="true"
                            height="300">
                        </VideoPlayer>
                        <GridLayout class="like-sect" columns="*,*" (tap)="like(item)">
                            <Image class="like" col="0" src="~/app/_assets/ui-images/like.png"></Image>
                            <Label col="1" class="likes" [text]="item.likes"></Label>
                        </GridLayout>
                        <StackLayout class="feed-info">
                            <Label class="caption" [text]="item.description" textWrap="true"></Label>
                            <Label [text]="item.username + ' | ' + item.dateCreated" (tap)="getUserById(item.userId)"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout class="hr" height="1"></StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

<!-- Instead of this stackLayout below, you should use RadListView and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the screen, it should automatically run the 'nextPage()' function -->

            <StackLayout>
                <Label *ngIf="!noMoreItems" class="load-more" horizontalAlignment="center" text="Load More.."
                    (tap)="nextPage()"></Label>
                <Label *ngIf="noMoreItems" class="load-more" horizontalAlignment="center"
                    text="You've viewed everything!"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

this is the typescript file incase anyone wants to see it:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FeedService } from '~/app/_mocks/feed.service';
import { EventService } from '~/app/_services/event.service';
import * as utils from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application"
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
import { Video } from 'nativescript-videoplayer';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GoToService } from '~/app/_services/go-to/go-to.service';
import { UserService } from '~/app/_services/user.service';
registerElement("VideoPlayer", () => Video);
import { screen } from "tns-core-modules/platform/platform"
import { environment } from '~/app/environments/environment';

@Component({
    selector: 'ns-feed',
    templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css']
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private mockFeedService: FeedService, private eventService: EventService
        , private router: RouterExtensions, private http: HttpClient, private goTo: GoToService,
        private userService: UserService) { }
    baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'feeds/'
    public isAndroid: boolean;
    public isIos: boolean;
    feeds: any;
    loaded = true
    today: '18/12/2019'
    show: any;
    start = 0
    end = 7
    pageNumber = 1;
    userImg = '~/app/_assets/-user.png'
    height: number = screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs * 1;
    noMoreItems = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        if (application.ios) {
            this.isAndroid = false;
            this.isIos = true;
        } else if (application.android) {
            this.isAndroid = true;
            this.isIos = false;
        }

        this.getFeed();
        this.show = 'false'
        console.log(this.feeds)
    }

    getFeed() {
        this.baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'feeds' + '?pageNumber=' + this.pageNumber
        this.http.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe(response => {
            const feeds = response;
            this.pushToUi(feeds)
            // console.log(this.feeds)
            if (!feeds) {
                console.log('no response')
            }
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    pushToUi(items) {
        if (items.length == 0) {
            console.log('no items')
            this.noMoreItems = true;
        }
        if (this.feeds) {
            this.feeds = this.feeds.concat(items)
        } else {
            this.feeds = items
        }
        // this.ArrayOptimization()
    }

    ArrayOptimization() {
        // if (this.feeds.length >= 5) {
        //     console.log('length > 5, length = ' + this.feeds.length)
        // }

        // THE CODE BELOW IS THE ACTUAL CODE THAT WILL BE USED:

        // THIS MAY NOT EVEN BE NECCESSARY, NEED TO DO TESTING

        // if (this.feeds.length >= 11) {
        //     this.feeds.splice(0, 5)
        //     console.log(this.feeds.length)
        // }
    }

    getUserById(item) {
        let newUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/users/' + item
        console.log(newUrl)
        this.http.get(newUrl).subscribe(response => {
            this.userService.singleUser = response;
            console.log(this.userService.singleUser)
            this.router.navigate(['/single-user/' + item])
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    like(item) {
        console.log(item.likes)
        item.likes = item.likes + 1
        console.log(item.likes)
    }

    goToUrl(url) {
        utils.openUrl('https://' + url);
    }

    loadVideoIOS() {
        this.router.navigate(['/video'])
    }

    nextPage() {
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1
        this.getFeed()
    }


}
```